# Java Sever Network - Connect specific clients to each other over the same port

Tags: java, networking, client, server

I have a chat app that connects to a server listening on port 4444.

Client1, Client2, and Client3 will connect to server on port 4444 and will want to talk to each other.

Client4, Client5, and Client6 will also connect to the server on port 4444 and will want to talk amongst each other as well.

I am stumped on how to distinguish the clients apart and how to get the right ones to be communicating with each other (Clients 1, 2, and 3 in one group. Clients 4, 5, and 6 in another).

Not sure if I"m on the right track, but I'm thinking right now, say Client1 connects first and passes along a title called "Alpha". Then Client2 and Client3 will connect and will search for the word "Alpha"? Then I put them into an array? How would I implement that in code if that's the track I'm suppose to be on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to reach your target but the question to the most fitting algorithm is your intention in detail. Do you want

- every client to choose his group manually by setting a String?
- every client to choose his group out of existing groups?
- every client to choose his group out of predefined groups from the server?

After you've found a way for each client to choose his group, the server will send each message from this client to all other clients within the group (maybe to the sender too to show that the message was successfully sent).

Comment: Still new to coding so I'm not really sure.. I guess basically Client1 will create a group called Alpha. Then Client2 and Client3 will join that group Alpha and they can all talk together through that. 

Are there any examples online for what I'm looking for? Or what keywords should I be searching? Thanks!

Comment: No problem that you're new to coding. But what kind of examples are you searching for? The algorithm inclusive the handling of the sockets, the creating/setting/choosing of the group as well as the forwarding of a clients message to the group is a big algorithm - nearly a chat program. If you are able to smaller the question it would be much easier to answer - otherwise you're asking for a whole chat program. ;-)

Comment: I guess handling and distinguishing the sockets right now. I've followed many simple chat apps... but none of them seem to deal with creating more than one group such that 2 or more different chats can go on simultaneously (granted, they're considered simple so they just stick with one chat group). Thanks!

Comment: I would try to use one these simple chat apps. There you probably'll find a List/Map/Set of Connections/Sockets of the clients and a place, where an incoming message is sent to all clients. Then I'd create a container for these Connections/Sockets, lets call the class GroupConnection - that is a simple Java class with a pointer to the Connection/Socket and a String for the group. Within the algorithm I'd then find the sender's GroupConnection and what group he/she is in. After that I would ask each GroupConnection what the group is and only when it matches, you sent it to this one.